# How to ensure Search bar sticks to the top in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have a table view along with search bar.

I want to ensure that while scrolling the tableview, the searchbar stays on top - always.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to Keep both of them separated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your search bar in the table's delegate callback

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Note: don't forget to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`